# how modify username in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

I create a username in oracle that has spelling mistake, I want to modify it now but I am not successful. would you please help me how I can modify my username in all_users table? 
I use oracle 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, as of version 11.2, you can't rename a schema (=user). See this [discussion on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30020192108317) for a workaround: you would export the user, reimport with the good name (using `FROMUSER` and `TOUSER`). All references (if any) in pl/sql code will have to be updated manually. Grants and public synonyms will have to be recreated separately.

Comment: @benoit: I was really curious to see if it's possible to rename a schema, but it looked too easy :)

Comment: If you think about it, it would be problematic since it would change the how every object in the schema is referenced.  For one thing it would have to modify code making it no longer in sync with your source repository.